# uWSGI client certificate authentication CRL

Tags: ssl, uwsgi, client-certificates

Looking at uWSGI docs, I see that I can specify a CA cert to check any incoming SSL requests and make sure they have a client certificate signed by that CA (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/HTTPS.html#client-certificate-authentication).

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
shared-socket = 0.0.0.0:443
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
https = =0,foobar.crt,foobar.key,HIGH,!ca.crt
http-to = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
```

My question is: what about a certificate revocation list? Can I tell uWSGI to also check a CRL file before completing the handshake? I don't see anything in the docs about this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do it with pure uWSGI, there is no such option right now. You will need additional server between uWSGI and clients to do that, or provide some third party plugin for uWSGI with that functionality.